# Why Firebase marketing turned to mobile only recently?

Tags: firebase, single-page-application

When I first played with firebase it looked to be a really good tool for both web and mobile development, but now it dropped `web` and started marketing as mobile only.

Did anything change in firebase so it is not good anymore for web development and in particular SPAs built with Angular and alike?

And more generally, are there any cons, why I shouldn't pick Firebase for a SPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deeper into Firebase docs, the answer why Firebase is marketing itself as a platform for Mobile App development is because most of its features support IOS and Android development, whereas only a handful of features support web development.

See the [Firebase Products page](https://firebase.google.com/products/) for the details, but the following features don't support web:

- Crashlytics
- Performance Monitoring
- Test Lab
- Google Analytics
- A/B Testing
- Remote Config
- App Indexing

So to answer my question, Firebase are focusing on serving mobile development community, while still supporting some of the features for Web and other platforms like Unity and C++.